# How to add Horizontal Rule to Outlook using Macro?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm having trouble adding a horizontal rule to outlook within my email body.

I'm creating a reply. I want to separate the reply text from the rest of the email body.

> Reply message in body of email with Horizontal rule below
>
> ---
>
> From: Last, First < email@example.com>

```
Sub AddHRToBody(strIn As String)
    Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oItem As Object
    Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()

    If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
        Set oReply = oItem.ReplyAll

        oReply.Body = strIn + "What do I put to add Horizontal Line" + oReply.Body

        oReply.Display
        oItem.UnRead = False
    End If
    Set oReply = Nothing
    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is a simplified version as I am pulling text from a file

Comment: Have you tried <hr>?

Comment: Yes it adds "<hr>". Is there a way to make the reply html type maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed you are updating `Body` which is the text body.  You need to update `BodyHtml` which is the Html body.  Remember that `strIn` needs to be Html.